# Using google transliteration in Flex

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache-flex, transliteration

Attached code is an example of how to use Google transliteration 
feature in certain html textboxes. I need to enable the same 
transliteration feature for a flex application. Is there a way 
I could do it?

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          // Load the Google Transliteration API
          google.load("elements", "1", {
                packages: "transliteration"
              });

          function onLoad() {
            var options = {
              sourceLanguage: 'en',
              destinationLanguage: ['hi','kn','ml','ta','te'],
              shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
              transliterationEnabled: true
            };

            // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
            // options.
            var control =
                new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

            // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
            var ids = [ "transl1", "transl2" ];
            control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

            // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
            // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
            control.showControl('translControl');
          }
          google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <center>Type in Indian languages (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)</center>
        <div id='translControl'></div>
        <br>Title : <input type='textbox' id="transl1"/>
        <br>Body<br><textarea id="transl2" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final working code :

ajax_api.mxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
        <mx:TextArea x="209" y="139" height="245" width="318"  id="text1" fontSize="28"/>
        <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import flash.external.*;

         public function callWrapper():void {
            var s:String;
            if (ExternalInterface.available) {
       ExternalInterface.addCallback("g", g);
               var wrapperFunction:String = "initialize";
               ExternalInterface.call(wrapperFunction,text1.text);

            } else {
               s = "Wrapper not available";
            }
            trace(s); 
         }
         public function g(str:String):void
         {
            text1.text = str;
         }

                        ]]>
        </mx:Script>
        <mx:Button x="75" y="50" label="Enter some text and click this button to see the transliteration output" click="callWrapper()" height="37"/>
    </mx:Application>
```

HTML Wrapper :

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">

<!-- 
Smart developers always View Source. 

This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
// -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<title>ajax_api</title>
<script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<script src="history/history.js" language="javascript"></script>
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<style>
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = 9;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = 28;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body scroll="no">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("language", "1");
function thisMovie(movieName)
{

    if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1)
    {
        alert("microsoft");
        return window[movieName];
    }
    else
    {
        return document[movieName];
    }
}

function initialize(input) {
      google.language.transliterate([input], "en", "hi", function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("transliteration");
          if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
            result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
            output = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
        thisMovie("ajax_api").g(output);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
        "width", "100%",
        "height", "100%",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "ajax_api",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
        "name", "ajax_api",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "ajax_api",
            "width", "100%",
            "height", "100%",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "ajax_api",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
            "name", "ajax_api",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
    + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
    + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="ajax_api" width="100%" height="100%"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="ajax_api.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="ajax_api.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                width="100%" height="100%" name="ajax_api" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The following flex code and javascript wrapper solves the problem. 
Still there is one problem. I have to click the transliterate button twice
in order to get the output. Seems like there is some delay from the javascript
function returning the value.
```

flex code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:TextArea x="209" y="139" height="245" width="318"  id="text1" fontSize="28"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import flash.external.*;

     public function callWrapper():void {
        var s:String;
        if (ExternalInterface.available) {
           var wrapperFunction:String = "initialize";
           s = ExternalInterface.call(wrapperFunction,text1.text);
           text1.text = s;

        } else {
           s = "Wrapper not available";
        }
        trace(s); 
     }

            ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button x="92" y="118" label="Transliterate" click="callWrapper()"/>
</mx:Application>
```

HTML Wrapper :

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">

<!-- 
Smart developers always View Source. 

This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
// -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<title></title>
<script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<script src="history/history.js" language="javascript"></script>
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<style>
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = 9;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = 28;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body scroll="no">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("language", "1");

        var output;
    function initialize(input) {
      google.language.transliterate([input], "en", "hi", function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
            result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
            output = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
          }
        }
      });
    return output;
    }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
        "width", "100%",
        "height", "100%",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "ajax_api",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
        "name", "ajax_api",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "ajax_api",
            "width", "100%",
            "height", "100%",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "ajax_api",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
            "name", "ajax_api",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
    + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
    + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="ajax_api" width="100%" height="100%"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="ajax_api.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="ajax_api.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                width="100%" height="100%" name="ajax_api" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the Google AS3 API at http://code.google.com/p/googleas3api/ but it does not support transliteration. I'm wondering if transliteration can be added in a similar way in AS3 as with the AS3 translate implementation. Anyone know how?